# Type mismatch when using unordered_map with Catch2 Predicate

Tags: c++

Catch2 gives a Predicate class to make our own matcher. https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/matchers.md

I simply test an unordered_map(`decltype(getEntity2IdMap()`) here.

```
namespace Generic {

Predicate<decltype(getEntity2IdMap())>(
    [&](auto& maps) -> bool {
        return maps.size() == 3 &&
            maps["entity1"] == 0 &&
            maps["entity2"] == 1 &&
            maps["entity3"] == 2; },
    "entities were inserted."));
```

The Predicate class has a simple definition.

```
template <typename T>
class PredicateMatcher : public MatcherBase<T> {
    std::function<bool(T const&)> m_predicate;
    std::string m_description;
public:

    PredicateMatcher(std::function<bool(T const&)> const& elem, std::string const& descr)
        :m_predicate(std::move(elem)),
        m_description(Detail::finalizeDescription(descr))
    {}

    bool match( T const& item ) const override {
        return m_predicate(item);
    }

    std::string describe() const override {
        return m_description;
    }
};

} // namespace Generic

    // The following functions create the actual matcher objects.
    // The user has to explicitly specify type to the function, because
    // infering std::function<bool(T const&)> is hard (but possible) and
    // requires a lot of TMP.
    template<typename T>
    Generic::PredicateMatcher<T> Predicate(std::function<bool(T const&)> const& predicate, std::string const& description = "") {
        return Generic::PredicateMatcher<T>(predicate, description);
    }
```

However, clang++ yields a type mismatch.

```
error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      unsigned int, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, unsigned int> > >'
```

I am wondering the `maps` type here or I misunderstood the lambda context for "/m/entity1".

Comment: `Predicate` constructs `PredicateMatcher` with a function taking `const T&`. But `unordered_map::operator[]` requires a non-const map object. Use `find` method instead, or `at()` if you are sure the key exists (or don't mind handling exceptions).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you move the comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message is likely to be something like:

```
<source>:7:21: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>' (aka 'const unordered_map<basic_string<char>, int>')

    std::cout << map["test" ] == 1;

                 ~~~^~~~~~~

unordered_map.h:963:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>' (aka 'const unordered_map<basic_string<char>, int>'), but method is not marked const

      operator[](const key_type& __k)

      ^

unordered_map.h:967:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>' (aka 'const unordered_map<basic_string<char>, int>'), but method is not marked const

      operator[](key_type&& __k)
```

The key clue is `'this' argument has type 'const.... but method is not marked const`.

Your maps are const but `operator[]` is not const, you need to use `find()` or `at()` to retrieve values from a const `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.